# rake aborted! cannot load such file -- yard

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant

I have been trying to add a vagrant plugin (https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus) from source. I downloaded it, did "bundle install", which went smooth. But when I did "rake install", it showed me the following error:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- yard
```

Here is the full error log with trace:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- yard
/root/chef-solo-example/vagrant-omnibus-master/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/root/chef-solo-example/vagrant-omnibus-master/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:589:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Here is the gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
ast (1.1.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.3.1)
chef (11.8.2)
chef-zero (1.7.2)
coderay (1.1.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
hashie (2.0.5)
highline (1.6.20)
io-console (0.4.2)
ipaddress (0.8.0)
json (1.7.7)
knife-solo (0.4.1)
librarian (0.1.0)
librarian-chef (0.0.2)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (1.16)
mixlib-authentication (1.3.0)
mixlib-cli (1.4.0)
mixlib-config (2.1.0)
mixlib-log (1.6.0)
mixlib-shellout (1.3.0)
moneta (0.7.20, 0.7.0, 0.6.0)
net-http-persistent (2.8)
net-ssh (2.7.0)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
net-ssh-multi (1.2.0, 1.1)
ohai (6.20.0)
parser (2.0.0)
powerpack (0.0.9, 0.0.6)
pry (0.9.12.4)
psych (2.0.0)
puma (1.6.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rainbow (1.1.4)
rake (10.0.4)
rake-compiler (0.8.3)
rdoc (4.0.1)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rspec (2.14.1)
rspec-core (2.14.0)
rspec-expectations (2.14.0)
rspec-mocks (2.14.0)
rubocop (0.15.0)
slop (3.4.7)
systemu (2.6.0, 2.5.2)
thor (0.17.0)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
yard (0.8.7.3)
```

Any idea what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 6):

You should use [`bundle exec` to "run the command in context of the bundle"](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_exec.html):

```
bundle exec rake install
```

If that does not work, maybe it’s a bug and yard is not even in the `Gemfile`. A temporary workaround would be to add this line manually to the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'yard'
```

Comment: Hmm... You can try updating `rake` with `gem update rake` and re-installing bundler with `gem install bundler`.

Comment: Still not working! Updated rake (to 10.1.0) and re-installed bundle. Then it said bundle requires 10.0.4, so I used "bundle exec" and back to square one! Same exact error. Though there is one thing I can see yard gem in "gem list" but not in "bundle show", could that be an issue?

Comment: if it's not in `bundle show`, then something is clearly wrong! You should also delete your `Gemfile.lock` and do `bundle install` again.

Comment: Is `yard` actually in the `Gemfile`?

Comment: Deleting Gemfile.lock didn't work! And yeah, yard is not in Gemfile, it's in Rakefile.

Comment: Ok then maybe it's simply a bug. Try adding `gem 'yard'` to the `Gemfile`, rerun the install and if that fixes it, be nice and file a bug so the gem authors can fix it ;-)

Comment: Ok edited the answer to help future visitors. If you provide a link to your bug report then Ican reference it, too. Consider upvote/accept if your problem is solved. Cheers!

Comment: It wasnt a bug with Rubygems, as they tell me it's the problem with the Gemfile of the product (I guess with vagrant plugin).

Comment: I had the same problem. tried all advice from this comment. still didn't work out

Answer (score 1):

Try to set right environment for you

for example

> Rails_ENV=test

Answer (score -4):

This following steps have solved my issue. It might help you too.

**1:** Try uninstalling Ruby.
**2:** While reinstalling check the 2nd and 3rd check boxes which asks to associate .rb files and executables.
**3:** Also check for the Path in environment variables has all correct path.